# Facebook graph api search results depends on location?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I've tried to fetch results using Graph search API and I've notice that the results when executed in my computer (Argentina) are different from the results when I run it in a server (France).

Is this like this? How can I force a location for a search?

Comment: I also met this problem. start a bounty. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks @Sascha Galley. I also find another easy way.

Just add  **&locale=en_US**  in `Facebook Graph search API` query `URL`.

[This is languages and locales list refrence](http://www.karakas-online.de/forum/viewtopic.php?t=858)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly which results are different and which skd version you are using, but one possible approach is to send the **accept-language** header with the cURL request. In the facebook api php file add the following line in the function `makeRequest()` below `$opts = self::$CURL_OPTS`;

```
$opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = array('Accept-Language: en-us,en;');
```

This post is almost two years old: [Get Facebook Graph API results in English](http://daniel-zahariev.info/devtt/?p=43)

Actually, this issue should have already been solved: [Return values from the graph-api depend on geographic server location](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/issues/75)

Comment: As u'r the first and right answer, give u the bounty. Thanks.