# get all post from a geolocalized facebook page

Tags: facebook-graph-api, geolocation

I want to get all posts from a facebook page that targeting the posts.

With the graph API I obtain only the post for my language and country. 
Is there any special call to the Graph API for obtain all the posts of the facebook page ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this guy has similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595518/facebook-graph-api-search-results-depends-on-location)