# Facebook graph results in English for ios

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am pulling graph results in via iOS in the following manner:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"place",@"type",
                               loc,@"center",
                               @"500",@"distance", 
                               nil];

[self.facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"search" andParams: params andDelegate:self];
```

Everything works fine and dandy. The problem that I'm having is that the place names are returned in Chinese (I assumed because the location is in from such a place). I know the places I am retrieving have English names because if you visit their facebook pages, it has an English name. Is there a way to set the language to English? I can't seem to find a setting for params for that.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the locale parameter:

```
locale=en_US
```

More info here:
[Facebook graph api search results depends on location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3595518/facebook-graph-api-search-results-depends-on-location)